# SocialEngine: getDbTable() vs. getItemTable()

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

I have often seen tables are retrieved in SocialEngine using `Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable()`.
For example:

```
$usersTbl = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('users','user');
$row = $usersTbl->createRow();
$row->user_id = $user->getIdentity();
$row->phone_number = $phoneNumber;
$row->save();
```

However, I also see that SocialEngine has used `Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable` in many places. For example:

```
$table = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable($type);
$row = $table->createRow();
foreach($params as $key=>$value) {
 if(isset($row->$key)) {
   $row->key = $value;
 }
}
$row->save();
```

What is the main difference between these two types of accesses, if any, and when is each one used?

Comment: I have edited answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/application/libraries/Engine/
```

`Engine` folder is SocialEngine CMS on top of zend, here you find all the function definitions

`/application/modules/moduleName/settings/manifest.php` [Here you add items, in a module]

when application is loaded, all manifest files are scanned and items are loaded.
`getItemTable` can only load, DbTable class when item is defined.

where as getDbTable() can be used for tables which are not used as Items.

Comment: I understand from your answer that items are modules that are loaded at startup from manifest files,  aren't they?

Comment: Items like activity, user,  album, video, music, etc. Am I wrong?

Comment: Items are tables, associated with modules. By adding them to items list. You can use it with `items` associated functions.